# In Java eclipse IDE, how to get all classes with the corresponding methods of a project in one view

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Please let me know, Is there any possibility to get all classes with the corresponding methods of a project in one view in eclipse IDE.

Outline view is there but that's for only one class but i need for whole projects.

Kind of outline view for the whole projects.

Thanks.

Comment: Compile a SonarQube report, building through Maven. Not an exact solution though.

Comment: I don't know of any such feature in Eclipse. The closest I've seen is the "java browsing" perspective which creates a more structured overview, but in no way a complete listing.

Answer (score 0):

### Point given by HighCommander4

I think I know understand what your 'corresponding' means. In fact you want to see all classes in your project with all their methods. Simple as that.

What you are looking for is the 'Package Explorer' view. Basically it shows an Overview over your workspace, but it can do much more.

To view all classes and methods, select the project you are looking for, right click its `src` folder and select `go into`. Unfortunately you now have to manually elapse all classes, as there is no `elapse all`; only a `collapse all`.

---

If you are just looking for classes with methods that 'look like' the method you are corresponding to, the 'Search' view is what you are looking for.

To perform a search for a specific method, simply mark or select it and press `Ctrl + Shift + G`.

However, the 'Search' view will go through your complete workspace, but you can group the results after projects.

**Edit:** I never knew of `Ctrl + Shift + G` until I read Thomas' answer just know. `Ctrl + G` brings up the 'Search' view, too, but somehow it filters the results to a specific project (**not** the selected one).

---

If you are looking for classes that implement the method you are corresponding to, the 'Type Hierarchy' view is what you are looking for.

To build up a type hierarchy for a specific method, simply mark or select it and press `Ctrl + T` for a quick context menu style or press `F4` to open the 'Type Hierarchy` view.

Comment: Yes but both of you did not read the question, which has absolutely nothing to do with searching.

Comment: Well, I read the question, and I cannot tell if searching would solve the problem or not. The phrase "get all classes with the corresponding methods" does not tell those attempting to help what it is they're after. What are 'corresponding methods'? Corresponding to what? OP needs to start with the assumption that we don't know what is wanted, and then explain that, not just throw terms around and expect readers to fill in what is meant. And getting snarky with people who are trying to help doesn't make anything any better.

Comment: You're right, it could as well be the type hierarchy. Updated answer.

Comment: I think the OP wants a view that shows all the classes in the project, and all their methods. Like a whole-project Outline view, instead of an Outline view for the current file.

Answer (score -1):

With the Shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+G` you can search for all references of a selected method.